# Corda - Get State Machine Feed from ServiceHub

Tags: corda

`CordaRPCOps` provides a mechanism to access the state machine feed

```
ops.stateMachinesFeed().updates.subscribe {
    ...
}
```

I want to be able to access the state machine feed from a Corda service. Is there an equivalent to this using `ServiceHub` or `AppServiceHub`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it at the moment. It requires accessing an instance of `StateMachineManager` and there is not a way to wire that into a service.

Comment: is this still holds?